# Определение физического местоположения устройства в проводной локальной сети

Tags: сеть

Ситуация такая: есть проводная локальная сеть со статическими ip-адресами, и к ней кто-то подключается со своего личного ноутбука по чужому ip-адресу из неизвестного места в пределах здания. Есть ли возможность определить используемый этим злоумышленником провод для входа.

Comment: Если известный ip, то можно узнать мак адрес. А зная первые 3 байта (6 символов, не считая двоеточия), можно определить модель материнки. Вполне возможно, что этого будет достаточно.

Comment: @KoVadim а если он его в кармане прячет?

Comment: в кармане с проводом? такого человека легко вычислить:)

Comment: @KoVadim вычислить легко, в карман залезть сложно.

Comment: А не нужно лезть в карман. Просто блокируем по маку на роутере и наслаждаемся. Но если это компания, то тут все легко решается административными методами.

Comment: @KoVadim MAC-адрес ведь поменять можно.

Comment: В этом случае можно и монтировкой по голове дать.

Comment: @KoVadim ))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу ответ, потому что боюсь в комментарий не влезет. Надо пояснить некоторые моменты.

Варианты какие приходят на ум
1) Выдёргивать провода из хаба|коммутатора и ждать пока злоумышленник не прибежит жаловаться: "У миня интернет пропал".

2) Так же выдёргивать провода из хаба|коммутатора. И пинговать злоумышленника до отключения, после отключения и после подключения кабеля.
Если он использует чужой адрес, то и пинговаться может чужой компьютер. Вообще при этом должен был бы быть конфликт адресов и нормально не мог бы работать ни злоумышленник, ни тот, чей адрес он захватил. Но всякое бывает. Кроме того злоумышленник может блокировать пинг.
Кроме ip-адреса у каждого устройства есть MAC-адрес. И каждое сетевое устройство хранит таблицу соответствия MAC и ip адресов, с которыми оно общается - таблицу arp. Практически все ОС имеют утилиты для просмотра и изменения этой таблицы.  Надо посмотреть таблицу и запомнить MAC-адрес злоумышленника. Перед каждым пингом таблица arp очищается. После пинга, даже если он не работает, проверяется появление в этой таблице MAC-адреса злоумышленника.
Есть ещё так называемый arp-ping или arping, который "пингует" не ip-адрес, а сразу MAC. В интернете можно скачать.

3) Если Вам повезло - у Вас коммутатор с управлением, то можно просмотреть его таблицу коммутации: MAC-адрес -> порт коммутатора. Да с таким коммутатором некоторые штуки можно на корню пресекать.

Comment: Спасибо. Третий вариант самый подходящий. А есть коммутаторы с таблицами выданный_ip->порт коммутатора?

Comment: @Bublik Не знаю. Вряд ли. IP выше уровня, на котором работают коммутаторы. Даже если такое и есть, то это что-то очень специальное и дорогое. Хотя может быть, точно уже не помню. Возможно есть коммутаторы со строенным dhcp-сервером, но и они могут знать только те адреса, которые раздают сами. Ну и конечно управляемые коммутаторы имеют такую же arp-таблицу как любое устройство. Но есть ли к ней доступ - не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо. Нужно будет прикупить коммутатор с управлением, про который Вы написали.

Comment: @Bublik лучше тогда уж сразу коммутатор с подержкой [IEEE 802.1X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X)

Comment: @PavelMayorov хороший комментарий.

Comment: @Bublik Главное не переборщите с количеством фич. А то как скажут - пусть лучше злоумышленник с нотебуком, чем такая неподъёмная в финансовом и кадровом плане инфраструктура.